# Lebesgue Integral is Linear

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I found the following statement without proving or explanation. It says:

"the Lebesgue integral is linear."

What does it mean?

Is it something to prove?

If yes, how could we prove it?

Comment: An operator T is linear if it satisfies two things, for inputs f and g and scalar a, T(f+g)=T(f)+T(g) and T(af)=aT(f). See if given arbitrary functions and scalars the properties hold.

Comment: @ Michael Dyrud Thank you  Michael

Answer (score 3):

It means $\int (af + bg) = a\int f + b\int g$, where $a$ and $b$ are any constants

Comment: One can say that "linear" means it _preserves linear combiations_.  @Fabian : Do you know what a linear combination is? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy I know the dependent and independent linear combination. Is it the same idea?

Comment: @Fabian : A linear combination of vectors $\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_n$ is a function $(\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_n) \mapsto a_1\vec{v}_1+\cdots+a_n\vec{v}_n$, where $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are scalars. The "vectors" can be functions. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @ Michael Hardy So you mean $\int (a_nf_n +....+a_0 ) = a_n\int f_n + ...+a_0\int 1$